# How to use MATCH against LIKE in IF clause? (MySql)

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to improve my query performance and use MATCH against LIKE.

My simplified strucure:

```
public:
- id (PRIMARY)
- title (FULLTEXT)
- ...

private
- id (PRIMARY)
- id_public (KEY)
- title (FULLTEXT)
- ...
```

I added fullindex like that:

```
ALTER TABLE public ADD FULLTEXT INDEX idx_title (title);
ALTER TABLE private ADD FULLTEXT INDEX idx_title (title);
```

Next I'd like to change my query but isn't simple.

In simple query I have changed query like that.

From

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public WHERE `title` LIKE '%XYZ%';
```

To

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('XYZ');
```

But I have query more specyfict with JOIN and IF. How can I use in this query MATCH?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM public as public
LEFT JOIN private as private ON private.id_public = public.id
WHERE IF(private.title IS NULL, public.title, private.title) LIKE '%XYZ%'
```

I hope someone help me. I've spent a lot of time to find solution and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's required that only one of the fields should be matched, then something like this should work

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM public as public
LEFT JOIN private as private ON private.id_public = public.id
WHERE
  (private.title IS NOT NULL AND MATCH(private.title) AGAINST ('XYZ'))
  OR
  (private.title IS NULL AND MATCH(public.title) AGAINST ('XYZ'))
```